# Comparing variables to multiple values and using "and" & "or in "If" condition vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am learning qtp and vbs mostly by myself. I need a function in qtp/vbs server 2008 that ads one day to current date then changes the places of dd and mm and transforms it to a numeric string for qtp to insert it to application under test. This is what I came up with, but the function gives back nothing at the end.

'5) DATEFORMATFUNC
'Function that gets current system date, adds one day to it and transforms it to a string
'usable as a date parameter in UAT "Flight Reservation"
Function DATEFORMATFUNC

```
'Defining variables
    Dim currentday, currentmonth, currentyear, oday, omonth, oyear, NextDayDate, LeapYear

    '*  Checking if current year is leap year and transforming answer to numeric variant  wher 1=True and 0=False
    If  DatePart("yyyy", Now) mod 4=0 then 
        LeapYear = 1
        Else LeapYear = 0
    End If


    '* getting current day of month 
    currentday = DatePart("d", Now)
    '* getting current month of  year
    currentmonth = DatePart("m", Now)    
    '* reporting to get it into "test results"
    Reporter.ReportEvent micDone, "Current month of year is  " & currentmonth, currentmonth

    '*  getting last two numbers of current year
    currentyear = Right((DatePart("yyyy", Now)),2)
    '*  reporting to get it into "test results"
    Reporter.ReportEvent micDone, "Current year is  " & currentyear, currentyear

    '*  If  currentday is 31(when 31 days in month) then date becomes the first day of next month
    If currentmonth = 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 8 or 10   and  currentday = 31 Then
        omonth = currentmonth +1  and  oday = 1

    '*  If  currentday is less then 31(when 31 days in month) then adding 1 day to currentday
    ElseIf currentmonth = 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 8 or 10 or 12   and  currentday < 31 Then
        oday = currentday + 1

    '*  if current day is 31 of december then date becomes first of january next year
    ElseIf currentmonth = 12  and  currentday = 31 Then
        omonth = 1  and  oday = 1 and oyear = currentyear+1

    '*  if current day  is 30 (when 30 days in month) then date becomes first day of next month
    ElseIf omonth = 4 or 6 or 9 or 11  and  oday = 30 Then
        omonth =currentmonth + 1 and oday = 1

    '*  if current day is less then 30 (when 30 days in month) then  adding 1 day to current day
    ElseIf currentmonth = 4 or 6 or 9 or 11  and  currentday < 30 Then
        oday = currentday +1

    '*  if it is leap year and current day is 28 of February then adding 1 day to current  day
    ElseIf currentmonth = 2 and currentday< 29 and LeapYear = 1  Then 
        oday = currentday +1

    '*  if it is leap year and date is 29 of  February then date jumps to first of March
    ElseIf currentmonth = 2 and currentday = 29 and LeapYear = 1  Then 
        oday = 1 and omonth = 3

    '* if it is not leap year and current day is 28 of February then date becomes first of March
    ElseIf currentmonth = 2 and currentday = 28 and LeapYear = 0  Then 
        oday = 1  and  omonth = currentmonth + 1 

    '*  if it is not leap year and current day is less then 28 then adding 1 day to current day
    ElseIf currentmonth = 2 and currentday < 28 and LeapYear = 0  Then 
        oday = currentday + 1 

    '*  End 
    End If



    'if  the day of the month is a one digit number then concatinating "0" before it
    If oday < 10 then
        oday = 0 & oday
    end If

    'if  the month of the year is a one digit number then concatenating "0" before it
    If omonth < 10 then
        omonth = 0 & omonth
    End If

    'concatinating the parts of the date in a manner that it can be used as a date parameter (mmddyy) for  "Flight Reservation"
    NextDayDate = omonth & oday & oyear

    Reporter.ReportEvent micDone, "Current date vs changed date", "Current date is: " & Date & " Changed date is: " & NextDayDate

    'reporting to get it into "test results"
    Reporter.ReportEvent micDone, "The parameter inserted to Data Table  " , DataTable.Value ("Next_Day_Date", dtGlobalSheet)

    'inserting parameter to data table
    DataTable.Value ("Next_Day_Date", dtGlobalSheet) = NextDayDate
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditions like your

```
If currentmonth = 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 8 or 10   and  currentday = 31 Then
```

don't 'work', because VBScript's logical operators do bitwise operations on numbers (cf. [Or](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6a4aywe%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/07/15/184431.aspx)):

```
>> For i = 0 To 1
>>     If i = 1 Or i = 2 Then
>>        WScript.Echo i, "is 1 Or 2"
>>     End If
>> Next
>>
1 is 1 Or 2
```

For `i = 0` the condition evaluates to `False Or False` i.e. `False`. But in

```
>> For i = 0 To 1
>>     If i = 1 Or 2 Then
>>        WScript.Echo i, "is 1 Or 2"
>>     End If
>> Next
>>
0 is 1 Or 2
1 is 1 Or 2
```

the `False` of `i = 0` is taken as the number 0 and bitwise Or'ed to 2 which is 2 and therefore `True`.

Before you add lots of `currentmonth =` to your conditionals, consider [DateAdd():](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb7z8yf9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

```
>> dtToday = Date()
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(dtToday), dtToday
>> dtTomorrow = DateAdd("d", 1, dtToday)
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(dtTomorrow), dtTomorrow
>>
Date 03.05.2015  ' german locale
Date 04.05.2015

>> For Each dtX In Array(#12/31/2014#, #2/28/2012#, #2/28/2013#)
>>     WScript.Echo dtX, DateAdd("d", 1, dtX)
>> Next
>>
31.12.2014 01.01.2015  ' german locale
28.02.2012 29.02.2012
28.02.2013 01.03.2013
```

And to format a Date as MMDDYYYY:

```
>> dtX = Date()
>> sX = Right(100 + Month(dtx), 2) & Right(100 + Day(dtX), 2) & Year(dtX)
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(sX), sX
>>
String 05032015
```

Comment: @Ekkehard.Homer  thank You for Your time answering my question!   I am working with hp qtp and it does not recognize WScript.Echo .

Comment: @GeorgeShtalmann - if you'd **study** my answer, you'd realize that WScript.Echo is just used for demo/display. DateAdd() and the workings of VBScript's boolean ops are relevant for your problem.